# Re-writing Stirling's series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

[image]

I have this problem where I need to rewrite the logarithmic form of Stirling's series

$$\ln(z!)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+(z+\frac{1}{2})\ln(z)-z+\frac{1}{12z}-\frac{1}{360z^3}+\frac{1}{1260z^5}-...$$

First I thought to use the logarithm properties:

$$\ln(z!)=\ln(\sqrt{2\pi}z^{(z+\frac{1}{2})})-\ln(e^z)+\frac{1}{12\ln(e^z)}-\frac{1}{360z^2\ln(e^z)}+\frac{1}{1260z^4\ln(e^z)}-...$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln(z!)=\ln(\sqrt{2\pi}z^{(z+\frac{1}{2})})+\ln(e^{-z})+\frac{\ln(e^{-z})}{12}-\frac{\ln(e^{-z})}{360z^2}+\frac{\ln(e^{-z})}{1260z^4}-...$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln(z!)=\ln(\sqrt{2\pi}z^{(z+\frac{1}{2})})+\ln(e^{-z})(1+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{360z^2}+\frac{1}{1260z^4}-...$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln(z!)=\ln(\sqrt{2\pi}z^{(z+\frac{1}{2})}e^{-z})(1+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{360z^2}+\frac{1}{1260z^4}-...$$

I get something similar but not quite right. The term of $\sqrt{2\pi}z^{(z+\frac{1}{2})}e^{-z}$ is really similar to the Stirling formula $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}*n^{(n)}e^{-n}$ but I still cannot get an idea to get the terms inside the parentheses of the answer the problem is giving me.

Comment: You used the logarithmic rules rather incorrectly. E.g., $\frac{1}{{\log a}} \ne \log (a^{ - 1} ) =  - \log a$. What you have to do is to take the exponential of both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\log (z!) \sim \tfrac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log z - z + \frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots .
$$
Taking the exponential of both sides gives
\begin{align*}
z! & \sim \exp \left( {\tfrac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log z - z + \frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
\\ &
 = \exp \left( {\log \left( {\sqrt {2\pi } z^{z + 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - z} } \right)} \right)\exp \left( {\frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)
\\ &
 = \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z + 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - z} \exp \left( {\frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right).
\end{align*}
To finish the derivation, we use the Maclaurin series of the exponential:
\begin{align*}
\exp \left( {\frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right) & = 1 + \left( {\frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right) + \frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots } \right)^2 }}{2} +  \ldots 
\\ &
 = 1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} - \frac{{139}}{{51840z^3 }} -  \ldots .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about Maclaurin series